# How to solve expss package loading problem

Tags: r, expss

I would like to install the expss package but it keeps returning an error.
Looked around for other with similar problems and tried re-installing several packages but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have a suggestion how to fixed the problem?

So far i tried re-installing:

install.packages("stringr")

install.packages("knitr")

install.packages("checkmate")

install.packages("htmlwidgets")

install.packages("htmltools")

install.packages("htmlTable")

install.packages("expss")

But Rstudio keeps returning with and error :

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘expss’:
 object 'mtfrm' not found whilst loading namespace 'expss'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/expss’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘expss’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/cl/5_wnd4b14y7b40zc80n1r3wdkcnbkn/T/RtmpdcLWsn/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - i tried this put it comes up with a worning: > install.packages("mtfrm")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mtfrm’ is not available for this version of R - i use R 4.2.2

Comment: Hmm.  I'm surprised that you say you're using R 4.2.2, as (1) the error message you cite refers to a path that looks like you're using 4.1 and (2)  the problem that I refer to below only occurs for earlier versions of R.  Can you please add the results of `sessionInfo()` (from a clean R session) to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/gdemin/expss/issues/98), the current version of `expss` won't install in versions of R before 4.2. This has recently been fixed in the development version. You could try:

- updating your version of R to version 4.2 (probably the simplest solution if you don't need to keep an older version of R)
- installing the development version of `expss` from GitHub: first install the `remotes` package, then `remotes::install_github("gdemin/expss")`
- install an older version of `expss` (`remotes::install_version("expss", "0.11.1")`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - it did the trick and the package run without any problem now

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.